# Draw Bounds with coordinates in QGIS from CSV

Tags: qgis, coordinates, csv, latitude-longitude

I have a CSV file that contains 4 coordinates on each line, 1 min latitude, 1 max latitude, 1 min longitude and 1 max longitude. These 4 points delimit a particular region(they are the bounds) I would like to draw for each row of my CSV, the region corresponding to the 4 points. How can I do that?

To be more clear this is what i want(done with OpenStreetMap): 
[image]

This is the csv:
[image]

In particular NORTH,SOUTH,WEST and EAST are the 4 coordinates that define my bounds

Comment: Can give a screenshot of your csv file, or provide the first 4 rows.

Comment: OK i added it. Look at the post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### How to convert east-west-north-south bounds to WKT formatted polygon

WKT format for polygons is like this:

> POLYGON ((x y, x y, x y, x y, x y))
>
> It's useful to note that the OGC standard definition requires a polygon to be topologically closed. It also states that if the exterior linear ring of a polygon is defined in a counter clockwise direction it will be seen from the "top". Any interior linear rings should be defined in opposite fashion compared to the exterior ring, in this case, clockwise. - [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-known_text)

So you need to convert your boundary lat/long values to corner coordinates. It helps to draw out the polygon, like so:

[image]

Starting at the southwest corner and proceeding counterclockwise, the WKT coordinates look like this:

> POLYGON ((W S, E S, E N, W N, W S))

In your spreadsheet, add a new column called WKT. Use the `concatenate()` function to combine the W-E-S-N values into WKT format.

> =CONCATENATE("POLYGON ((", C2, " ", E2, ", ", D2, " ", E2, ", ", D2, " ", F2, ", ", C2, " ", F2, ", ", C2, " ", E2, "))")

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I would import my data 4 times using the Add Delimiter 4 times:

[image]

West-South
West-North
East-North
East-South

Merge the layers and then use the Points2One plugin (not available in Qgis3x)

[image]

[image]

[image]

Group your layers by Region. You might need to create intermediary ids to sort the order of you points in the merged file.

[image]

I hope this helps.

Answer (score -1):

create well-know-text polygons in your spreadsheet-programm and import this wkt-polygons

Comment: could you please expand on this answer? How would you go about doing this? Please provide the OP with more information so they can adequately repeat the process.