# Creating a shapefile from .csv file on QGIS to clip NetCDF files with Python

Tags: qgis, python, shapefile, csv, netcdf

I have a .csv file containing bounding boxes of cities I want to study. I have NetCDF files I'd like to clip and I understood that, with Python, using shapefiles was the easiest way to go.

I added a column in my csv.file with the WKT column (to draw the bounding boxes [as mentioned in this post](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/297183/draw-bounds-with-coordinates-in-qgis-from-csv)) to but I can't get a visual representation of the bounding boxes on QGIS, how should I import it and create a shapefile with it? While trying to import the .csv data is written on QGIS that "X and Y must be chosen".

My goal is, at the end, to create a shapefile with all of the bounding boxes such that I can use it to filter my NetCDF files with Python.

EDIT (1)

The .csv file I want to import has the following form

```
;longmin;latmin;longmax;latmax;wkt
Rennes;-1.72;48.08;-1.61;48.15;POLYGON ((-1.72 ,48.08, -1.61 ,48.08,-1.61,48.15, -1.72, 48.15,-1.72 ,48.08))
Bursa;29.01;40.17;29.15;40.23;POLYGON ((29.01 ,40.17, 29.15 ,40.17,29.15,40.23, 29.01, 40.23,29.01 ,40.17))
Copenhagen;12.45;55.61;12.67;55.73;POLYGON ((12.45 ,55.61, 12.67 ,55.61,12.67,55.73, 12.45, 55.73,12.45 ,55.61))
Porto;-8.69;41.14;-8.55;41.19;POLYGON ((-8.69 ,41.14, -8.55 ,41.14,-8.55,41.19, -8.69, 41.19,-8.69 ,41.14))
Delhi;77.05;28.48;77.35;28.80;POLYGON ((77.05 ,28.48, 77.35 ,28.48,77.35,28.80, 77.05, 28.80,77.05 ,28.48))
```

EDIT (2)

What I get when I go on add a PostGIS layer, pardon my french.  [image: QGIS interface in french]

Comment: Can you post an example of the csv?  Does a single line look something like x0,y0,x1,y1,x2,y2,x3,y3.  I wrote a similar plugin.

Comment: I edited the post with some examples of the rows.

Comment: Please post  example CSV data as ASCII, not image.

Answer (score 2):

I think your csv will work as is. You will not need to write any Python code. If you select Layer from the main menu and then select **Add Delimited Text** from the drop down menu.  [image: Add delimited Text Layer]

You will have to select the column that contains the WKT geometry.  Also, you can label the column WKT to make it easier.
[image: WKT Column]

Also I found that the Longitude, Latitude pairs are separated by a space in WKT.

```
name;longmin;latmin;longmax;latmax;wkt
Rennes;-1.72;48.08;-1.61;48.15;POLYGON ((-1.72 48.08, -1.61 48.08,-1.61 48.15, -1.72 48.15,-1.72 48.08))
Bursa;29.01;40.17;29.15;40.23;POLYGON ((29.01 40.17, 29.15 40.17,29.1 40.23, 29.01 40.23,29.01 40.17))
```

Comment: In "Add PostGIS Layers" I do not have the same interface as you, I am new to QGIS. I am asked to build a connexion, I posted a picture in the edited post. For Python, I need to use it after I build the shapefile from QGIS to clip the NetCDF files I have. ***I try to use QGIS to build a shapefile from a csv file I am trying to import, in order to clip NetCDF files with Python***. If you know a more direct way to clip a NetCDF file, I'd be glad to know, but we can't ask these type of questions on Stack exchange I believe...

Comment: Add Delimited Text

Comment: You should now be able to export a shapefile from QGIS.  I have not worked with NetCDF data yet.